# WebRTC audio is not working in lock screen using CallKit

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, lockscreen, callkit

I have tried many solutions from here but no one is working. WebRTC is working fine and I get connected status when accepting the call while the device is locked and after the unlock the audio opens and video starts. How could I get only audio when the screen remains locked?

**I have enabled RTCAudioSession and disabled it when the call stops.**

It's working fine when the device is unlocked the first time and when I lock it back I'm getting the audio. But the first time, when I answer the call from **CallKit**, it is not working. It only starts working after the device is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of your specific problem, but what I learnt from similar issue while integrating CallKit with WebRTC, you must acquire camera and microphone access only inside the `DidActivateAudioSession` method of your implementation of the `CXProviderDelegate` class. Otherwise, you will get weird issues.